# Is there a response content filter in litespeed web server?

Tags: litespeed

I being new in Litespeed, I used to use the Nginx web server, but now I have a business that I must use Litespeed. And my problem is, is there any content response filter in Litespeed? In Nginx, I used to use the sub_filter module.

I've searched in Google about this, but the solution not found